# Oracl SQL remove non-identical duplicates from multiple self join

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a table with multiple people in the same Suite
I need to match on the suite then display each person as the First Id just Once with their list of room mates.

Because their are more than just two, i am running into scenarios where i have multiple results where the First Id is listed multiple times and room mates are ordered differently or I can only bring back one row with the 4 IDs

Example:

I have a table like this:

```
Table Name: ROOM_LIST
```

---

```
ID | BUILDING | SUITE | ROOM
01 | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_1
02 | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_2
03 | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_3
04 | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_4
05 | BU_1     | SU_2  | RO_1
06 | BU_1     | SU_2  | RO_2
07 | BU_2     | SU_1  | RO_1
08 | BU_2     | SU_1  | RO_2
```

---

I tried a query like this:

```sql
select A.ID as Primary,
       B.ID as Roomate_1,
       C.ID as Roomate_2,
       D.ID as Roomate_3,
       A.BUILDING as Building,
       A.SUITE As Suite,
       A.ROOM As Room
from ROOM_LIST A
Left Join ROOM_LIST B on A.BUILDING = B.BUILDING and A.SUITE = B.SUITE
Left Join ROOM_LIST C on A.BUILDING = C.BUILDING and A.SUITE = C.SUITE
Left Join ROOM_LIST D on A.BUILDING = D.BUILDING and A.SUITE = D.SUITE
where A.ID > B.ID
and   A.ID > C.ID
and   A.ID > D.ID
and   B.ID > C.ID
and   B.ID > D.ID
and   C.ID > D.ID
order by Primary,Roomate_1,Roomate_2,Roomate_3,Building,Suite,Room;
```

Which gets rid of extra duplicates but I only get one row per a Suite instead of one row with each ID as the Primary.

Also tried a similar one but with <> or != instead of > and then i get multiple duplicates with one id as the first but the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th are interchanged, so they are technically not duplicates.

Which is why i say "non identical" duplicates :)

### My end Results would look like this:

```
| Primary | Roomate_1 | Roomate_2 | Roomate_3 | Building | Suite | Room
| 01      | 02        | 03        | 04        | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_1
| 02      | 03        | 04        | 01        | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_2
| 03      | 04        | 01        | 02        | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_3
| 04      | 01        | 02        | 03        | BU_1     | SU_1  | RO_4
| 05      | 06        | Null      | Null      | BU_1     | SU_2  | RO_1
| 06      | 05        | Null      | Null      | BU_1     | SU_2  | RO_2
```

---

I have tried multiple queries with different sub-select in the select statement or in the from, but i cant seem to get it down to one result per an ID as the Primary. I've looked into doing a pivot, but (my understanding) would only work if I had the same id having multiple results and i wanted to turn the multiple results into columns.

Thought about a Union, but i dont know how to do query across unions? if that is even a thing

Any assistance would be appreciated

EDIT: The below Solution **only works in 12C**, but I need an 11G Solution:

```
  with dt as (
    select 01 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 02 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual union all 
    select 03 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_3' room from dual union all 
    select 04 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_4' room from dual union all 
    select 05 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_2' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 06 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_2' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual union all 
    select 07 id , 'BU_2' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 08 id , 'BU_2' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual )
    SELECT  
    A.ID as Primary,
            ( select id from (select id,rownum rn from dt  b where  a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite and b.ID != a.ID  order by id ) where rn=1)  Roomate_1,
            ( select id from (select id,rownum rn from dt  b where  a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite and b.ID != a.ID  order by id ) where rn=2)  Roomate_2,
            ( select id from (select id,rownum rn from dt  b where  a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite and b.ID != a.ID  order by id ) where rn=3)  Roomate_3,
           a.BUILDING as Building,
           A.SUITE As Suite,
           A.ROOM As Room
    FROM
        dt a 
    order by Primary,Roomate_1,Roomate_2,Roomate_3,Building,Suite,Room
```

I added following to one of the given answers: `and b.ID != a.ID` and changed `rn=2 to rn=1` to start the count because of 0

Comment: Thanks moore1emu.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: One other question I hoped to raise -- is the "priority" or designation of which roommate is "roommate_1" vs "roommate_2" important?  In the example, bu_1, su_1 has roommates 1-2-3-4, 2-3-4-1, 3,4,1,2, 4,1,2,3.  What if it were, for example, 1-2-3-4, 2-1-3-4, 3-1-2-4, 4-1-2-3 ?

Comment: Oracle 11G. The order does not matter. as long as each person is listed as the primary only once. i may have an issue where the room is the same, which means they are not just suite mates, but in the same room. but that is down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about performance impact. Will need to do the analysis but gives the result as expected.

12c Answer.

```
    with dt as (
    select 01 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 02 , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual union all 
    select 03 , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_3' room from dual union all 
    select 04, 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_4' room from dual union all 
    select 05 , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_2' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 06 , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_2' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual union all 
    select 07 , 'BU_2' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 08 , 'BU_2' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual )
    SELECT  
    A.ID as Primary,
            ( select id from (select id,rownum rn from dt  b where  a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite  order by id ) where rn=2)  Roomate_1,
            ( select id from (select id,rownum rn from dt  b where  a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite  order by id ) where rn=3)  Roomate_2,
            ( select id from (select id,rownum rn from dt  b where  a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite  order by id ) where rn=4)  Roomate_3,
           a.BUILDING as Building,
           A.SUITE As Suite,
           A.ROOM As Room
    FROM
        dt a 
    order by Primary,Roomate_1,Roomate_2,Roomate_3,Building,Suite,Room
```

11g answer. I am not sure how much ordering of data into roommate1 to roomate3 column is necessary.

```
WITH  dt as (
    select 01 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 02 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual union all 
    select 03 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_3' room from dual union all 
    select 04 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_4' room from dual union all 
    select 05 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_2' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 06 id , 'BU_1' building,  'SU_2' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual union all 
    select 07 id , 'BU_2' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_1' room from dual union all 
    select 08 id , 'BU_2' building,  'SU_1' suite ,'RO_2' room from dual ),
joindrslt AS (
    SELECT a.*, b.id roommate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.suite, a.building, a.room ORDER BY b.id ) AS ri
    FROM 
    dt a 
    JOIN dt b ON a.building = b.building AND a.suite = b.suite AND b.id != a.id
    ORDER BY b.id
)
SELECT ID Primary,
            roomate_1,
            roomate_2,
            roomate_3,
            Building,Suite,
            Room  FROM
    (
        SELECT
            * 
        FROM
            joindrslt PIVOT (
                MAX ( roommate )
                FOR ri
                IN ( 1 AS roomate_1, 2 AS roomate_2, 3 AS roomate_3 )
            )
    )
ORDER BY
 Primary,Roomate_1,Roomate_2,Roomate_3,Building,Suite,Room
```

Comment: i cant seem to get this to work. i keep getting this error: ORA-00904: "A"."SUITE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 97

I tried using it with the real data, but i get the same type of error.

Comment: Which oracle version are you using? I could run this in Oracle live SQL site.

Comment: 11G version 11.2

Comment: I ran it against sqlfiddle 11gR2 and i get the same error. so i am wondering if its a 12C or 18c thing

Comment: Yes, IT ran fine in 12c. So it looks like 11g does not support passing predicate two level down into the sub query.

Comment: any idea what the 11g version of this is? This does make sense why i couldn't get some of my queries to work despite the info i was finding online that it should work

Comment: Now that i have looked closer at the results, this is not working correctly even in 12c. The results are showing the primary id and one of hte roomate id as the same number. see picture: https://ibb.co/txKVMQQ

Comment: I fixed the query and was able to get it to work correctly in 12c. i'll add it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: the query that you posted does not work in 11g either. Can you please post the query that works on 11g?.... I get below error. "ORA-00904: "A"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191280/discussion-between-jignesh-and-moore1emu).

Comment: The 11g solution works perfect, thank you so much. I would have never figured that out. Did not even think about the difference between 11g and 12c when i started working on this issue.